# Reuse Asynctask in several classes

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask

I have two different asynctasks. One to make GET requests and another to make POST requests.

In my application, I have to make several requests so I'd like to be able to reuse the code I wrote.

```
public static class performGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog progress;
    Activity activity;
    Boolean progressBarRequired;

    public FragmentDelivery.GetResponse delegate = null;//Call back interface

    public performGetRequest(Boolean progressBarNeeded, Activity act, FragmentDelivery.GetResponse asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse;//Assigning call back interfacethrough constructor
        activity = act;
        progressBarRequired = progressBarNeeded;
    }
```

With this code I'm only able to call this asynctask from FragmentDelivery fragment. How could I call this class from any other class?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The same way you call it from `FragmentDelivery`. Possibly move `GetResponse` to its own class

Comment: You mean by adding the same code but changing "FragmentDelivery" for another class?

Answer (score 1):

just create your own interface.

```
public static interface PerformInterface {
public void mycallback();
}
public static class performGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog progress;
    Activity activity;
    Boolean progressBarRequired;

    public PerformInterface delegate = null;//Call back interface

    public performGetRequest(Boolean progressBarNeeded, Activity act, PerformInterface asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse;//Assigning call back interfacethrough constructor
        activity = act;
        progressBarRequired = progressBarNeeded;
    }
}
```

and implement it by any other clas you want.

for example

```
extends Activity implements PerformInterface {

///.... 
@Override
public void mycallback() {
//your code
}
}
```

in the same way you can override even `FragmentDelivery.GetResponse`